# Power Point VBA - Change color of each bar

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to change color of bar to red or green based on value.
Code works fine on Column chart but does not work on waterfall chart. It says "This action is not supported."

Please help making below code waterfall chart compatible:

```
Sub UpdateBarColor()

    Dim p As Point
    Dim s As Series
    Dim c As Chart

    Set c = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
    Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)

    For Each p In s.Points
        Debug.Print p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changes the bars in a waterfall chart to be gray (that's the RGB)
You should be able to modify it to suit your needs

```
Set c = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

   For Each p In c.Points
        p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(169, 169, 169)
    Next
```

Getting xvalues from the chart, try this

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
arr = .XValues
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
Debug.Print arr(i)
Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how to get values from waterfall chart? If I say arr = c.XValues here, it gives same error again, "Object doesn't support this action"

Comment: Thanks but for waterfall chart statement arr = .XValues give error "Object doesn't support this action."

Comment: I have uploaded my file with only one slide here, if you want to take a look: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OhWuczZBq-Bs5thytUMmCBwUBNwbuPsU

Comment: Basically if value is negative, I need to make bar red and green otherwise.

Comment: You can loop through the points (like in the color example) and just evaluate with p.Value < 0